# puts statements in production

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

It happens many a times that in development mode to debug we intensively use **puts** statements and later miss to remove them when the code moves to production. Does removing them help us increase the response time? I am unable to test this scenario in local as they get printed in the server console, but in production i'm sure they are not getting printed in any of the logs. I'm also curious if they are executed then where is the output directed to in production. Is there a way to find out?

Comment: Patching `Kernel.puts` to be a wrapper around `Rails.logger.debug` might not be a bad idea if you make this mistake frequently. It's also worth noting you can avoid these by carefully reviewing your commits to your version control system. If you're not using one of those, you need to address that problem first.

Comment: in response to whether they hurt much for response time speed you can "always profile" (my guess is they don't).  If you're in a webserver they probably by default go to /dev/null...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First, don't use `puts` sprinkled everywhere. Bottleneck your "debug" output in a single method. That way you can very easily control the output, redirect it, massage it, etc. For instance, these might be the growth from a simple logging method to something more sophisticated:

```
def debug_output(s)
  STDERR.puts s
end

---

DEBUG_OUTPUT_MINIMUM_LEVEL = 3
def debug_output(s, level=DEBUG_OUTPUT_MINIMUM_LEVEL)
  STDERR.puts s if level >= DEBUG_OUTPUT_MINIMUM_LEVEL
end

---

require 'logger'

LOGGER_OUTPUT_FILE = '/path/to/log/output'
def debug_output(s)
  @logger ||= Logger.new(LOGGER_OUTPUT_FILE)
  @logger << s
end
```

There are better tools available to you than `puts` though. Learn to use the [debugger](https://github.com/cldwalker/debugger), or [PRY](https://github.com/pry/pry) in debugging mode and/or use Ruby's built-in [Logger](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.0/libdoc/logger/rdoc/index.html) or [Syslog](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.0/libdoc/syslog/rdoc/index.html) so you can control the debugging level output.

Historically, Ruby's documentation for using Syslog was pretty... lacking. In Ruby v2.0 it's *MUCH* improved and quite well documented now, so if you want real power look at either Logger or Syslog and Syslog::Logger.

This is from the documentation for Syslog. Consider the impact to your code debugging/logging if you could do these things:

> Syslog messages are typically passed to a central logging daemon. The daemon may filter them; route them into different files (usually found under /var/log); place them in SQL databases; forward them to centralized logging servers via TCP or UDP; or even alert the system administrator via email, pager or text message.

Comment: I will take a look at the Syslog documentation.

Answer (score 0):

It is for certain that having `puts` increases response time. The real question is how much. If you have a console open, then it will take up much time. I usually use emacs instead of a console, and just having things printed out on the emacs shell mode sometimes takes enormous time. But no matter how less the extra time is, there is no reason you should not remove them when you do not need them.

In the long run, what the Tin Man suggests is right, but if you want to be lazy and do a temporal hack, one way to deal with it is to overwrite `puts` to do nothing.

```
def puts *_; end
```

Comment: Somewhere between zero and very hard to measure. It would take a lot of them to delay a page even 1ms.

Comment: @tadman Not necessarily. On emacs shell mode, the difference is huge.

Comment: And we all know that emacs is an operating system. :-)

Comment: Nobody runs production websites in emacs shell mode.

Comment: @theTinMan Of all the editors out there, only EMACS tries to be an operating system.

Comment: I have used ruby-prof gem and did some profiling in my local. I have directed the output to NUL(dev/null equivalent in Unix) in my windows console. I could see that puts was taking up significant time. In production i could see improved response time after removing the statement as we were inspecting and then printing a very big hash in loop.